# Setting parameters of enum using spring config

Tags: java, spring, enums

I've an `enum` say, `A`,

```
enum A
{
  TYPE_1 (true, false)
  {
    public func(A a, B b, C c)
     {
     }
  },
  TYPE_2 (FALSE, TRUE)
  {
    public func(A a, B b, C c)
     {
     }
  };

  X x;
  Y y;
  Z z;

  protected A(X x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public abstract func(A a, B b, C c);

}
```

Since, the the variables with type `Y` and `Z`, are not part of constructor but are used in the implementations of `func`. I want them to be injected from spring. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Java question ?

Comment: Spring use injection for beans. In you case just write bean that do desired work in post process phase.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318454/inject-bean-into-enum