# how to inject a dependency in a java enum?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to inject a bean into an enum but i keep getting null pointer exception when call to someMethod is made.

The answer mentioned in this [Inject bean into enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318454/inject-bean-into-enum/16318603) worked for me. I want to know why my code didn't work

```
@Component
public class DataProvider {

public int method1() {
//somecode
}

}

public enum Genres {

DRAMA(1,”Drama”);
ADVENTURE(2,”Adventure”);
HORROR(3,”Horror”);

private int id;
private String name;

@Inject DataProvider dataprovider;

public int someMethod() {
return dataprovider.method1();
}

}
```

Comment: If you want to inject something in an enum, it's no more an enum, but a class. Keep enums simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the answer you linked does is loop the `enum` values and use a setter to inject the `DataProvider` dependency

```
public void postConstruct() {
   for (ReportType rt : EnumSet.allOf(ReportType.class)) {
      rt.setDataPrepareService(dataPrepareService);
   }
}
```

It works because the `ReportTypeServiceInjector` class is an inner, `static class`, and so it can be seen and instantiated by Spring.

It's a crazy design anyway. Avoid it.
Ultimately, keep the enum simple and extract the `DataProvider` usage.

Your original code didn't work because Spring cannot `@Autowire`/`@Inject` dependencies in `enum`s.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I scratching my head over the linked answer too and your answer saved me some browsing

Answer (score 1):

- Generally, it is not a good practice to have dependency injection in enums as they are designed to be constants/static ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html))

But, I agree with you, many times, we need to associate some real time behavior to be encapsulated along with Enum values.

I would suggest, create a new class and encapsulate Enum within that.

```
class GenresService{
 // 1st option: Declare Genres enum reference at class level and 
 // initialize using class constructor/injection.

 // Genres g;

 @Inject DataProvider dataprovider;

 //2nd option: pass Genres value to method at real time.
 public int someMethod(Genres g) {
    return dataprovider.method1();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have any injection to work you would need to have your `enum` also managed. You could try to inject your `enum` but how and what would you inject? It presents constant values and in addition it has private no args constructor.

So the way you might have it working would be some JNDI lookup  - that initializes `dataProvider` - inside your `someMethod()` or using some static context accessor.

And: for for Spring it is not `@Inject` but `@Resource` or `@Autowired`

Comment: Spring works with Inject too. Also you're going OT with JNDI

Comment: @LppEdd Yes correct if you add `javaee-api` it will work.