# @Inject = @Inject, is it possible?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-8

I'm using Java EE 8 and I have next enum. The question is **is it possible assign to the one injected variable the value of another injected variable within one class** like on the next line?

```
public enum CommandEnum {

    EMPTY_COMMAND {
        {
            this.command = emptyCommand;
        }
    },
    NAME_GENERATION {
        {
            this.command = nameGenerationCommand;
        }
    },
    NAME_GENERATION_SETTINGS {
        {
            this.command = nameGenerationSettingsCommand;
        }
    },
    SIGNIN {
        {
            this.command = signinCommand; // is it possible?
        }
    };

    @Inject
    @EmptyCommandQualifier
    Command command;
    @Inject
    EmptyCommand emptyCommand;
    @Inject
    NameGenerationCommand nameGenerationCommand;
    @Inject
    NameGenerationSettingsCommand nameGenerationSettingsCommand;
    @Inject
    SigninCommand signinCommand;

    public Command getCommand() {
        return command;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Enum`s are not created through the bean container. Therefore, I would be surprised if we were able to inject anything in an `Enum` in this way.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew that enums aren't supported by CDI

Comment: But the question is actual, because i meant is it possible to assign injected field of one type the value of another injected field with the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - but only after CDI had a chance to inject a value. [CDI supports `@PostConstruct` annotation for this purpose](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/cdi-basic014.html):

> To Initialize a Managed Bean Using the `@PostConstruct` Annotation
> Initializing a managed bean specifies the lifecycle callback method that the CDI framework should call after dependency injection but before the class is put into service.
>
> 1. In the managed bean class or any of its superclasses, define a method that performs the initialization that you require.
> 2. Annotate the declaration of the method with the `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation.
>
> When the managed bean is injected into a component, **CDI calls the method after all injection has occurred and after all initializers have been called**.
>
> Note:
> As mandated in JSR 250, if the annotated method is declared in a superclass, the method is called unless a subclass of the declaring class overrides the method.

Adding the method below will have an effect you are looking for:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init () {
    this.command = signinCommand;
}
```